# Python web scrapping hidding items

Tags: python, web-scraping

(Note Im new)

Im trying to scrap data from this url
https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/OlVbxLtwTToL-Senior-IT-Specialist-Orient-Qalubia-Egypt

Data I need > Experience Needed
its in *`"span",class_="css-4xky9y"`*
thie reply shoes as 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfDTo.png)

Issue here withought the user-Agent I cant scrap the data?
when its already readable if inside soup
but the code is a bit weird to me ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8th4b.png)

I need to understand in a spesific way that can teach me more + solve this & why its not readable witought user agent & later I want to know how to paybass the im not a robot.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import zip_longest

HEADERS=({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36','Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.5'})
src=requests.get(link,headers=HEADERS)

soup=BeautifulSoup(src.content,"lxml")

exp=soup.find_all("div",class_="css-rcl8e5")
print(exp)
```

Comment: Without the user-agent header, the site thinks the request came from a robot (which it did) and it decides not to talk to a robot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `User-Agent` to get the right data. In fact, the data is stored in Json form inside `<script>` element, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it.

To parse the data you can use next example:

```py
import json
import re

import requests

url = "https://wuzzuf.net/jobs/p/OlVbxLtwTToL-Senior-IT-Specialist-Orient-Qalubia-Egypt"

data = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"initialStoreState = (.*);", data)
data = json.loads(data.group(1))

slug = url.split("/")[-1]
for job in data["entities"]["job"]["collection"].values():
    if job["attributes"]["slug"] == slug:
        # print(job)
        title = job["attributes"]["title"]
        exp = job["attributes"]["workExperienceYears"]
        print(title)
        print(exp)
        break
```

Prints:

```
Senior IT Specialist
{'min': 3, 'max': 5}
```